# ManyToMany incluir outros campos

Tags: java, hibernate

Olá, tenho um relacionamento `ManyToMany`entre `envio`  e `carro`, e gostaria de entender como faço para salvar na mesma tabela, que é criada através deste relacionamento, o id da entidade `Local`.

`Entidade` Envio ( através deste relacionamento é criada uma tabela chamada envio_carro, com id do carro e `id` do envio.)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idEnvio")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "dataEnvio")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dataEnvio;

@Column(name = "dataRecebimentoLocal")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dataRecebimentoLocal;

@Column(name = "dataDevolucao")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dataDevolucao;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "envioCarro", referencedColumnName = "idCarro")
private Carro carro;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "envioLocall", referencedColumnName = "idLocal")
private Locall locall;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "envio_carro", joinColumns
        = @JoinColumn(name = "envio_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns
        = @JoinColumn(name = "carro_id"))
private List<Carro> carros;
```

`Entidade` Carro

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idCarro")
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "numeroCarro")
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "carros")
private List<Envio> envios;
```

`Entidade` Local

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = “Locall.findAll”, query = “SELECT distinct s FROM Locall s”),
@NamedQuery(name = “Locall.findByLocallId”, query = “SELECT s FROM Locall s WHERE s.id = :id”),
@NamedQuery(name = “Locall.findByLocallDescr”, query = “SELECT s FROM Locall s WHERE s.descricao = :descricao”)})
public class Locall implements Serializable, EntidadeBase {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idLocal")
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "descricaoLocal")
private String descricao;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "carro")
private List<Envio> envios;
```

Consegui através dos exemplos daqui mesmo, criar o `ManyToMany`, a duvida agora é: é possível ( ou ainda , é correto) nesta tabela ( originada pelo `ManyToMany`) incluir o `id` do `Local`, pois tenho vários `carros`, sendo enviados para vários `locais` e cada carro está vinculado a um `envio`, ou tenho que mudar a abordagem?

Comment: Se você já tem o `local` dentro de envio, não seria melhor vc pegar ele? Se você tem uma relação manyToMany então vc tem um carro e envio, nessa relação vc consegue pegar o envio e então o local do mesmo

Comment: Posso ter errado nos relacionamentos até aqui, pois  faço um `envio` para um `local`. Entretanto depois os usuários podem "redirecionar" o `carro` enviado deste primeiro `local`, para um novo `local`. Quando crio o `envio` vai tudo para o mesmo local

Comment: Pelo o que foi descrito, quando ele redirecionar para outro local, seria como editar o atributo local, correto? Se for isso, qual seria o custo em criar uma entidade associativa entre essas entidades? Quem sabe uma entidade `DestinoEnvioCarro` talvez. Aí ficaria centralizado em um ponto só o teu controle quanto ao envio.